# Setting css properties with javascript not working on strict mode?

Tags: javascript, css, doctype

I'm embarassed to admit that I can't find the standards-compliant method to modify CSS properties using Javascript. Or at least, I assume so, due to the following:

The following piece of code works fine in Firefox/WebKit without a DOCTYPE declaration, but doesn't work with the doctype specified (either HTML 4 or 5):

```
function setWindowSize(width, height)   {
    console.log("Syncing dimensions:",width,height);            // prints correct values
    var container = document.getElementById('canvasProxy');
    console.log(container);                                     // prints valid element
    console.log(container.style);                               // prints valid object
    container.style['width'] = width;
    container.style['height'] = height;
    console.log(container.style['width'], container.style['height']); // prints empty values
}
```

where canvas proxy is simply defined as:

```
<div id="canvasProxy"></div>
```

and has no style associated with it. The above code does not execute until after the DOM has loaded.

style.setProperty and style.getPropertyCSSValue also fail to work. So uh...what's the correct form? Am I going crazy?

(I'm betting that jQuery could handle this just fine, but I'm trying to keep page size at an absolute minimum in this particular case.)

Comment: You would do well to move to jQuery which makes this type of stuff a snap and easy across all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what values you are passing, or what you consider to be correct, but I'd give good odds that you are passing *integers* and not *lengths*.

CSS requires units on lengths other that 0. Most browsers will perform error recovery (in direct contradiction to the CSS specification) and assume you mean `px` if  you fail to specify a unit … but only in Quirks Mode.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('canvasProxy').css('width', 300);
    $('canvasProxy').css('height', 50);
</script>
```